# Db2 Security Bulletins points to v11.5.8 fixpack that don't yet exists, is it?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, patching

I have found three security bulletins [IT40893](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT40893), [IT40781](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT40781), [IT41338](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT41338) that all as solution recommends: *"Upgrade to DB2 Version 11.5.8 or higher"*, but I can't find Db2 fixpack v11.5.8 on official [Db2 fixpack download web page.](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-db2-fix-packs-version-db2-linux-unix-and-windows)

1. Is there fixpack v11.5.8 already released, but I have missed it?
2. Are maybe security this bulletins from last week (date 2022-09-13) referencing to fixpack v11.5.8 that is not yet released?

Comment: It's not released yet, but these APARs are planned to be included into this modification.

Comment: Is there any ETA of fixpack 8?

Comment: It's better to ask your IBM sales representative on this. These ETAs aren't published usually. Or open a Case with IBM support on this.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 v11.5.8.0 was released on 19.Oct.2022.

Download web page:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6830623

Now security bulletins make sense, because fixpack is now available for download.